# css3 columns collapse in bootstrap on screen-size change

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i'm developing a wordpress theme usign bootstrap, which displays post using css3 columns.

is there a way to say to bootstrap that on desktop it must render 3 columns, on mid-size screens (ex tablet), it must render 2 columns, and 1 for small screen?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to tell bootstrap how big is a column on a specific viewport size, also, there is a way to tell it to hide/show columns depending on the viewport size. For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  Column1 Content
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 hidden-xs">
  Column2 Content
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 hidden-md hidden-xs">
  Column3 Content
</div>
```

The above code will work as follows:

Desktop Device will show:

```
<!-- 33.3333% width for each column -->

Column1 Content | Column2 Content | Column3 Content
```

And on tablets and medium screens

```
<!-- 50% width for each column -->

Column1 Content | Column2 Content
```

And finally on smaller screens and mobile devices

```
<!-- 100% width column -->

Column1 Content
```

You can tweak your layout using `[hidden|visible]-[lg|md|sm|xs]` to hide/ show columns depending on the viewport size. Imagine how much responsiveness you can achieve using these grid classes ;)

---

Reference:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities